# Node generation from json data for force layout

Tags: json, d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to do a bubble chart similar to [Mike Bostock's](http://bl.ocks.org/1804919):

[image]

However, instead of randomly generating the nodes, I want them to be generated for a json. Suppose I have a `dataset` variable that is a valid JSON how do I generate a `nodes` variable from this that can be used for the force layout.

Mike's implementation (for randomly-generated circles) is:

```
var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
      v = (i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random());
  return {
    radius: radius(v),
    color: color(i),
    cx: x(i),
    cy: height / 2
  };
});
```

Let's suppose my `dataset` JSON is something like:

```
{"nodes":[{"name": "node_name", "size": 18}, ... ]}
```

And I want the radius of each circle to be the `size` of each object in the JSON array.

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON data you're starting from?

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodes` is an array of objects which each have `radius`, `color`, `cx` and `cy` attributes. All you need to do is create such an array from your data. How exactly to do this will depend on your data. Note that you don't need to create all the attributes -- if all the nodes can have the same color for example, you don't need to add the corresponding attribute (but also need to change the code that actually sets the color later on).